# How to make a macro that adds a macro to each document in a list of documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have made a macro that I'd like to put into a long list of word files.  I'd like to write a macro to open up each file and add the macro to it.  I have no problem going through the files, opening them, saving them, and closing them, however, for the life of me I can't figure out how to add the macro (with a macro button in the document).  I almost got it with the following code below.  This code works as is and adds a MsgBox macro with a button to a new document.  This is great, but when I add my code, in place of MsgBox, it is apparently has too many line breaks to store as a string.... or something.

```
Sub Test()
    'Add a command button to a new document
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim shp As Word.InlineShape
    Set doc = Documents.Add

    Set shp = doc.Content.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1")
    shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "Click Here"

    'Add a procedure for the click event of the inlineshape
    '**Note: The click event resides in the This Document module
    Dim sCode As String
    sCode = "Private Sub " & shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name & "_Click()" & vbCrLf & _
            "   MsgBox ""You Clicked the CommandButton""" & vbCrLf & _
            "End Sub"
    doc.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString sCode
End Sub
```

Comment: You only get a limited number of line continuations in a single string, but you can break up your code into multiple strings and then join those to get the final code.  Or read your code out of a text file: e.g. `myCode = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject").opentextfile("C:\stuff\code.txt").readall()`

Comment: You can also export the module you want to add to each file, then import it into each.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()    
    Dim FILE_NAME As String
    Set FILE_NAME = "C:\Path\To\Your_Module.bas" 'Export your module here

    Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import (FILE_NAME)
        'Make sure you enable programmatic access in your application to
        'allow programatically adding modules / code

        'Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings-> "Trust Access to VBA Object Model"
End Sub
```